# Bootstrap - Fixed-navbar covering body content via mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the navbar to not cover the body content, when it's dropped down, for mobile devices. Any ideas what should I do so it can be more mobile-friendly? Thanks.

Here a snippet of my code :

```html
<header>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AT Products LLC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="collapsibleNavbar" style="">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">AT Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/paid">Paid Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/flash">Flash Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/sms">SMS Bomb</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/mdickie">MDickie Projects</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Communities</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu show" data-bs-popper="none">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/ehs">Ethical Hacking Society</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/script">The Script Community</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/codinghome">CodingHome</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/noodle">Noodle Hackerspace</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Documentation</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/terms">Terms of Service</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/discord">Discord Rules</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
        </header>

<body>
Body of the page
</body>
<style>
    header {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       right: 0; 
       left: 0;
       z-index: 1030;
    }
    
    body {
        padding-top: 56px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: If you don't want it to go into the body, where do you want it to go?

Comment: The body should be under the expanded navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sticky position  instead of fixed position for your header

```
position: sticky
```

```html
<header>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AT Products LLC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse show" id="collapsibleNavbar" style="">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">AT Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/paid">Paid Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/flash">Flash Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/sms">SMS Bomb</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/mdickie">MDickie Projects</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle show" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Communities</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu show" data-bs-popper="none">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/ehs">Ethical Hacking Society</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/script">The Script Community</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/codinghome">CodingHome</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/noodle">Noodle Hackerspace</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Documentation</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/terms">Terms of Service</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/discord">Discord Rules</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
        </header>

<body>
Body of the page
</body>
<style>
    header {
       position: sticky;
       top: 0;
       right: 0; 
       left: 0;
       z-index: 1030;
    }
    


</style>
```

Comment: Didn't quite work. Just made it like the element never existed.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean, like sticky did not do anything.

Comment: But now, your body is not covered by the header when your are on mobile / computer like in the snippet. I must have misunderstood the request

Comment: Sticky just made the navbar have padding at the top. What I am looking for is something like https://getbootstrap.com.

Comment: Did you remove the `padding-top:56px` of the body ? In the bootstrap page, the navbar is also in sticky position.

Comment: Can confirm that I did remove the padding from the body.

Comment: I'm sorry then, but I don't understand what you want compared to the snippet I gave. 
I don't know if you have a picture or something else that can show me your problem of padding, but if you really want the same style as Bootsrap for the header, the best is to inspect the page.